# mysql declare variable syntax error

Tags: mysql, function

I am trying to migrate a scalar valued function of MS SQL to function in MySQL and have been using the following syntax as Queries to create function named xx4.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `xx4`;`
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER FUNCTION `xx4`(code VARCHAR(3))`
RETURNS CHAR`
BEGIN
`DECLARE coden INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0= CAST(CODE AS UNSIGNED)`
    `DECLARE ret CHAR =CASE` 
    `when coden<50 then 'A'` 
    `when coden<100 then 'B'` 
    `when coden<350 then 'C'` 
    `when coden<360 then 'D'` 
    `else null` 
`END`
`RETURN ret`
`END;
```

It gives me error as:

> at Declare ret char=Case when coden<50 then 'A' when coden<100 w' at line 4

Can you please tell me where I am wrong? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think it needs further edit as the syntax appears with too many symbol  of ` .

Comment: `default 0=`? what's that supposed to be? trying to set `coden` to be the boolean result of `0=cast(...)`? default values can't be expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why there are so many backticks, but the following syntax works (mind your semicolons):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS xx4;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER FUNCTION xx4(`code` VARCHAR(3))
RETURNS CHAR
BEGIN
DECLARE coden INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 = CAST(`CODE` AS UNSIGNED);

    DECLARE ret CHAR;

    set ret = CASE 
    when coden<50 then 'A' 
    when coden<100 then 'B' 
    when coden<350 then 'C' 
    when coden<360 then 'D' 
    else null    
    END;

RETURN ret;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I would suggest adding ` around code as it's a keyword.

Comment: Done, as Jason Heine suggested

Comment: I ran your syntax but returns with error at line 4.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer at your convenience.

Comment: Hi udog, where do I accept the answer? I couldn't fine the option.

Comment: Info here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (basically, click the check mark)